# Return the item at the specified position in list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to find out en element at a particular position in a list using recursive function. The function takes 2 parameter, an int & list. int is the position of the item in the list. I have specified 2 cases, 1st case for empty list provided and 2nd case for non- empty list.

.hs code

```
findKthElem :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> a
findKthElem x [] = error "empty list provided"
findKthElem x (y:ys) = if x==1 then y else findKthElem (x-1) ys
```

**Input**

```
*Main> findKthElem 0 [1..99]
```

**Output**

```
** Exception: empty list provided
```

**Expected Output**

```
 1
```

Since I'm a newbie in Haskell I can't understand where I'm going wrong. Please Help.

Comment: Follow your code and ask yourself what happens when you call that with a 0 argument.  That follows the "else" path of your code, which makes a recursive call with x-1...

Comment: if x== **0** then

Comment: @MarcTalbot Thanks!! seems my recursion skills are not good. How would the above code change for the input "findKthElem 50 [1..9]"???

Comment: Why the `Ord` constraint?

Comment: Minor point: the error message could be less specific, since `findKthElem 100 [1,2,3]` will reach the empty-list case, even if the list is not empty, causing a puzzling error message.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using guards to match against different index values:

```
findKthElem :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> a
findKthElem _ [] = error "empty list provided"
findKthElem i (x:xs) | i < 0 = error "invalid index"
                     | i == 0 = x
                     | otherwise = findKthElem (i - 1) xs
```

You can also use the `Maybe` monad to remain error free:

```
findKthElem :: Ord a => Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
findKthElem _ [] = Nothing
findKthElem i (x:xs) | i < 0 = Nothing
                     | i == 0 = Just x
                     | otherwise = findKthElem (i - 1) xs
```